# get pairs of rows when a specific condition is met python

Tags: python

```
         date   sent
0  2022-06-01   true
1  2022-06-02   true
2  2022-06-04  false
3  2022-06-08   true
4  2022-06-09   true
5  2022-06-10  false
6  2022-06-11  false
7  2022-06-12  false
8  2022-06-12   true
9  2022-06-14   true
```

I need to get rows where the last false (e.g index 5 and 6 just the last one) and the following true are saved.
So I need pairs of these two.
I want to calculate the time difference between messages that have been sent by us (sent = true) and after we recieved a message from a customer (sent = false)

so i want two have a second df like this

```
         date   sent
2  2022-06-04  false
3  2022-06-08   true
7  2022-06-12  false
8  2022-06-12   true
```

I tried to do it with iterrows but i don't know how to apply the logic to get the last false and not all falses
I also tried a solution someone gave me before

```js
out = df[~df.sent | ~df.sent.shift(fill_value=True)]
```

but this gives me all falses  and i need just need the pair with true and not the one before which are not followed by a true

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the intermediate, you can compute the difference directly.

Use a boolean mask and `shift`:

```
# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# identify False followed by True
# you can easily adapt to identify the True
m = df['sent'].shift(-1)&~df['sent']

# slice True, subtract last False
df.shift(-1).loc[m, 'date'].sub(df.loc[m, 'date'])
```

Output:

```
2   4 days
7   0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you prefer to have the index of the True as reference:

```
m = df['sent']&~df['sent'].shift(fill_value=True)

df.loc[m, 'date'].sub(df.shift().loc[m, 'date'])
```

Output:

```
3   4 days
8   0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you really want the intermediate:

```
df[m|m.shift()]
```

Output:

```
        date   sent
2 2022-06-04  False
3 2022-06-08   True
7 2022-06-12  False
8 2022-06-12   True
```

##### masks

```
        date   sent sent.shift(-1)  ~sent      m m.shift()  m|m.shift()
0 2022-06-01   True           True  False  False       NaN        False
1 2022-06-02   True          False  False  False     False        False
2 2022-06-04  False           True   True   True     False         True
3 2022-06-08   True           True  False  False      True         True
4 2022-06-09   True          False  False  False     False        False
5 2022-06-10  False          False   True  False     False        False
6 2022-06-11  False          False   True  False     False        False
7 2022-06-12  False           True   True   True     False         True
8 2022-06-12   True           True  False  False      True         True
9 2022-06-14   True            NaN  False  False     False        False
```

Comment: can you explain me what happens  


m = df['sent'].shift(-1)&~df['sent'] here with ~

and here df[m|m.shift()]

Comment: `df['sent'].shift(-1)`: move all rows up relative to the index (try it!). `&` vectorial boolean AND, so you need True & True to have True. `|`: vectorial boolean OR, to get rows in the mask OR the next ones.

Comment: I also added the masks to help.